# Why is my mysql output giving much more zeroes than needed?

Tags: mysql, database

I just wanted to ask what I may have wrong because right now, my database shows correct values.

I used this code

```
    ALTER TABLE user_list
MODIFY balance DECIMAL(12,4) zerofill;
```

But instead of the output just being 150, it shows 15000000000

Anywhere I may be wrong? Everything's set up properly as well.

Comment: hard to say, without being able to reproduce. An [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would help immensely.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev demo cant reproduce the problem http://rextester.com/YHMV66542

Comment: what was the previous datatype of balance?